# Use .htaccess to redirect a site to a different url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to redirect a user who visits my site to another site.

suppose I have a site `http://example.com` and I would like to redirect a user who visits the above URL to `http://example2.com`

So in my cpanel of `example.com` I have created a .htaccess file and added

```
# BEGIN WordPress
  Redirect 301 / /http://example2.com/

# END WordPress
```

Example 1 and 2 are the representations of my site but in the htacess. I've used the actual site name. The above work failed.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Try removing the space at the start of the Redirect line? Not sure that'll make any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove one slash before 'http', like this:
    Redirect 301 / http://example2.com/

[here](https://support.totalchoicehosting.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/31/0/webpage-redirect-using-cpanel-or-htaccess) described two ways to make redirect in cpanel